# Using Induction to prove a product series equality?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, natural-numbers

I'm getting confused by these types of problems where "n" appears in the general term:

Use Induction to prove: 
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{n+i}{2i-3}= 2^n(1-2n)$$

Would my P(n+1) be this?:

$\mathbf P(n+1):$ $$\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{n+1+i}{2i-3}= 2^{n+1}(1-2(n+1))$$

If this is the case, I dont know how to use the Inductive hypothesis to prove it since the product sequence is now a "different" sequence.

How would I go about solving this?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: the index was indeed wrong, thanks T Ford, changed it to i=1

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE :) Good first question.

Comment: ^Is one of the statements wrong? Because won't the index i=0 have an effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a go:
$$\prod_{i=0}^n\frac{n+i}{2i-3}=\frac{\prod_{i=0}^nn+i}{\prod_{i=0}^n2i-3}$$
Firstly:
$$\prod_{i=0}^nn+i=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(2n)=\frac{(2n)!}{(n-1)!}$$
and:
$$\prod_{i=0}^n2i-3=(-3)(-1)(1)(3)=3*n!!$$
so:
$$\prod_{i=0}^n\frac{n+i}{2i-3}=\frac{(2n)!}{3(n-1)!*n!!}$$
since in this case our double factorial is odd,
$$n!!=\frac{(n+1)!}{2^{(n+1)/2}((n+1)/2)!}$$
giving:
$$\prod_{i=0}^n\frac{n+i}{2i-3}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n-1)!}*\frac{3*2^{(n+1)/2}((n+1)/2)!}{(n+1)!}$$
Not sure if this is on the right path but its my attempt

Answer (score 0):

Your stated equality is false. In order to fix this the index $i$ has to start with $1$ instead of $0$ otherwise the RHS will have a slightly different shape. However, first of all I have to say that this problem is quite unfitting to be attack via induction, at least in the way you tried to do. More convenient is the way *J.R.* proposed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/662497).

Using the idea of *Henry Lee* we may rewrite the product as the following

$$\prod_{i=0}^n\frac{n+i}{2i-3}=\frac{\prod\limits_{i=0}^nn+i}{\prod\limits_{i=0}^n2i-3}$$

The upper product can be intepreted as [Pochhammer Symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) whereas the denominator can be rewritten as [double factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html). Using these functions we further get

$$\frac{\prod\limits_{i=0}^nn+i}{\prod\limits_{i=0}^n2i-3}=\frac{(n)_{n+1}}{(-3)(-1)(2n-3)!!}=\frac13\frac{(2n)!}{(n-1)!}\frac{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(2n-2)!}=\frac{2^{n-1}}{3}(2n)(2n-1)$$

> $$\therefore~\prod_{i=0}^n\frac{n+i}{2i-3}~=~\frac{2^n}{3}n(2n-1)$$

The same technique can be applied for $i=1$ as start index. From hereon we get

$$\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{n+i}{2i-3}=\frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^nn+i}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n2i-3}=\frac{(n+1)_{n+1}}{(-1)(2n-3)!!}=-\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!}\frac{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(2n-2)!}=-2^{n-1}(2)(2n-1)$$

> $$\therefore~\prod_{i=0}^n\frac{n+i}{2i-3}~=~2^n(1-2n)$$